# Breadth-first algorithm on adjacency matrix: premature ending of search, returns queue of size 1?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

`adj` is an adjacency matrix:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

`adj` maps adjacency for a maze below (to the side is the element #):

```
S X E | 0 1 2
O O O | 3 4 5
O X O | 6 7 8
```

I'm using the adjacency matrix to traverse elements in the maze. Here's a Breadth-first-search algorithm to traverse the matrix.

```
queue Q = new queue();
boolean[] visited = new boolean[];
int num = 9; //number of elements
int begin = 0; //begin point as defined 'S'
int end = 2; //end point as defined 'E'
private queue BFS(int[][] adj, int begin) {
    visited[begin] = true;
    Q.enqueue(begin);
    while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
        int element = Q.dequeue();
        int temp = element;
        while (temp <= num) {
            if ((!visited[temp]) && (adj[element][temp] == 1)) {
                if (temp == end) {
                    return Q;
                }
                Q.enqueue(temp);
                visited[temp] = true;
            }
            temp++;
        }
    }
    return Q;
}
```

Doing `BFS()` returns a queue of `size()` `1`. Specifically, the queue only contains `begin` (in this case, `0`). The algorithm should produce a queue of `[0, 3, 4, 5, 2]`. Inserting a `System.out.println("blah")` right after the first `while()` opening shows it only iterates once.

Why does my algorithm stop prematurely? How can I tweak it to get my desired output? My goal is to device an algorithm that finds the shortest path possible between '0' and '2' in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the condition `temp == end` at the first iteration because your temp starts from 0, then it's 1 without inserting element to queue(because it's not adjacent to 0), then it's 2 without inserting, and here you are, under condition `temp == end` (both equal 2) you return Q that contains only `begin` as nothing yet has been inserted. So you only have one iteration of outer loop and three iterations of inner loop.

I would suggest following modification

```
queue Q = new queue();
boolean[] visited = new boolean[];
int num = 9; //number of elements
int begin = 0; //begin point as defined 'S'
int end = 2; //end point as defined 'E'
private void BFS(int[][] adj, int begin) {
    visited[begin] = true;
    Q.enqueue(begin);
    while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
        int element = Q.dequeue();
        if (element == end) {
            return Q;
        }
        int temp = 0;
        while (temp < num) {
            if ((!visited[temp]) && (adj[element][temp] == 1)) {
                Q.enqueue(temp);
                visited[temp] = true;
            }
            temp++;
        }
    }
    return Q;
}
```

Comment: If you want to know the shortest path once you end, instead of returning `Q`, it may be better to define `int visited[] = new int[num]`, use `-1` as meaning not-visited, and set `visited[temp] = element` in the inner loop. Once you finish, the shortest path can be found following `visited[end]`, `visited[visited[end]]` ... until you reach `start`

Comment: I'm working with your code @maggot092 and it returns a queue `[8]`.

Comment: @riista May be. This queue only have a sense of vertices you are planning to visit, so it means that at the point of the return statement algorithm planned to visit 8. If you want to get a path pay attention to tucuxi comment.